Tkinter timer decrementing by 1 without waiting for .after function when being restarted mid-program
I've been trying to make a timer in Tkinter, but I'm currently facing an issue with how the timer is decrementing; I have yet to figure out how I can track the exact milliseconds elapsed before a timer is stopped to ensure the counting of seconds remains accurate, and in the meantime I'm focusing on an alternative solution which is to use the .after function to subtract 1 from self.total_seconds every 1000ms elapsed
However, this only seems to work when starting the timer for the first time, and while it is counting down the seconds. But when I stop the timer and press the start button again, the timer decrements by 1 instantly, meaning the .after function has been skipped somewhere in the code, but I can't figure out where. My current approach was to have a flag to check whether the timer was restarted, and to run the .after function if this was the case, but this also proved ineffective.
Timer Class:
class Timer(MainWindow):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__() # Inherits basic app features

        self.on = False # Controls whether time has started or not

        self.timers = {
            "Pomodoro": [25, 0],
            "Short Break": [5, 0],
            "Long Break": [10, 0]
        }

        self.current_timer = self.timers["Pomodoro"]
        self.total_seconds = (self.current_timer[1] * 60) # For the divmod function to calculate minutes and seconds
        self.restarted = False
        self.after_function = None
        # self.timer_start = None # Time since starting
        # self.timer_end = None # Time at end

Timer section:
def start_up(self):
        current = tk.Frame(self.root, bg="#FFFFFF") # This is required to place buttons onto the screen
        time_left = ttk.Label(current, text=f"{self.current_timer[0]:0>2}:{self.current_timer[1]:02}", font="Arial, 50", background="#FFFFFF")
        # :0>2 is to pad the number with zeros.


        def time_controller(): # Controls start and stop buttons
            if not self.on:
                self.on = True
                start_stop['text'] = "Stop"
                if self.restarted:
                    self.root.after(1000, decrement_time)
                    self.restarted = False
                else:
                    decrement_time()

            elif self.on is True:
                self.on = False
                self.restarted = True
                start_stop['text'] = "Start"

        def second_down():
            self.total_seconds -= 1
            decrement_time()

        def decrement_time(): # Timer itself
            if not self.on: # Removes any possible delay by checking the condition FIRST
                return # Procedure end if not True
            
            self.current_timer[0], self.current_timer[1] = divmod(self.total_seconds, 60) # divmod returns the quotient and the remainder, or the minutes and seconds respectively. I don't have to explain this.
            time_left['text'] = f"{self.current_timer[0]:0>2}:{self.current_timer[1]:02}" # updating the label
            if self.total_seconds > 0 and self.on: # This will keep going as long as self.on is True, and timer has not elapsed
                self.after_function = self.root.after(1000, second_down)
            else:
                return

I tried various approaches already, like counting the seconds elapsed using time.time(), but I couldn't figure out the logic of how to implement it.
Edit 1:
I realised that I'm supposed to cancel the after function once I stop the timer to prevent different timers overlapping, but even this hasn't solved my original issue;
def time_controller(): # Controls start and stop buttons
    if not self.on:
        self.on = True
        start_stop['text'] = "Stop"
    if self.after_id is not None:
        self.root.after_cancel(self.after_id) # Cancel current count, if any
        self.root.after(1000, decrement_time)
    else:
        decrement_time()

    if self.on is True:
        self.on = False
        start_stop['text'] = "Start"


def decrement_time(): # Timer itself
    if self.after_id is not None: # Doubling down on cancelling the current time loop, before starting a new one
        self.root.after_cancel(self.after_id)
        self.after_id = None

    if not self.on: # Removes any possible delay by checking the condition FIRST
        return # Procedure end if not True
    
    self.current_timer[0], self.current_timer[1] = divmod(self.total_seconds, 60) # divmod returns the quotient and the remainder, or the minutes and seconds respectively. I don't have to explain this.
    time_left['text'] = f"{self.current_timer[0]:0>2}:{self.current_timer[1]:02}" # updating the label
    if self.total_seconds > 0 and not self.after_id: # This will keep going as long as self.on is True, and timer has not elapsed
        self.total_seconds -= 1 # Decrementing the time
        self.after_id = self.root.after(1000, decrement_time)
    else:
        return

Whole code snippet;
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import time

# tkinter for GUI, tkk for nicer, smoother widgets
# time for time increment


    class MainWindow:
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
            # *args allows you to pass an undisclosed number of parameters to this function, allowing for more flexibility.
            # This will put the elements you've passed into a tuple.
    
            # **kwargs generates a dictionary, as each parameter you'll pass will be associated with a keyword (variable name)
            # Example; App(a=2, b=3, c=4), etc..., and a, b and c would be the keys of this new dictionary.
            # So you have to refer to the values by kwargs.values(), to iterate through the values and not the keys
            # Purpose here; unclear
    
    
            self.root = tk.Tk() # Setting up an instance of tkinter
            self.root.title("Pomodoro Timer") # Setting window title
            self.root.geometry("500x400")
            self.root.resizable(False, False) # Not resizable on any axis
    
            # Menu
            self.menu_bar = tk.Menu(self.root) # initialising menu, main bar
    
            #Sub menu - these represent the different options along the menu.
            self.settings_menu = tk.Menu(self.menu_bar, tearoff=False)
            self.menu_bar.add_cascade(label='Settings', menu=self.settings_menu) # Adding option to the menu
    
            self.root.configure(menu=self.menu_bar) # Setting it as the window's menu bar rather than packing it into the window
    
    
    
    
    class Timer(MainWindow):
        def __init__(self) -> None:
            super().__init__() # Inherits basic app features
    
            self.on = False # Controls whether time has started or not
    
            self.timers = {
                "Pomodoro": [25, 0],
                "Short Break": [5, 0],
                "Long Break": [10, 0]
            }
    
            self.current_timer = self.timers["Pomodoro"]
            self.total_seconds = (self.current_timer[1] * 60) # For the divmod function to calculate minutes and seconds
            self.after_id = None
    
    
    
        def start_up(self):
            current = tk.Frame(self.root, bg="#FFFFFF") # This is required to place buttons onto the screen
            time_left = ttk.Label(current, text=f"{self.current_timer[0]:0>2}:{self.current_timer[1]:02}", font="Arial, 50", background="#FFFFFF")
            # :0>2 is to pad the number with zeros.
    
    
            def time_controller(): # Controls start and stop buttons
                if not self.on:
                    self.on = True
                    start_stop['text'] = "Stop"
                if self.after_id is not None:
                    self.root.after_cancel(self.after_id) # Cancel current count, if any
                    self.root.after(1000, decrement_time)
                else:
                    decrement_time()
    
                if self.on is True:
                    self.on = False
                    start_stop['text'] = "Start"
    
    
            def decrement_time(): # Timer itself
                if self.after_id is not None: # Doubling down on cancelling the current time loop, before starting a new one
                    self.root.after_cancel(self.after_id)
                    self.after_id = None
    
                if not self.on: # Removes any possible delay by checking the condition FIRST
                    return # Procedure end if not True
                
                self.current_timer[0], self.current_timer[1] = divmod(self.total_seconds, 60) # divmod returns the quotient and the remainder, or the minutes and seconds respectively. I don't have to explain this.
                time_left['text'] = f"{self.current_timer[0]:0>2}:{self.current_timer[1]:02}" # updating the label
                if self.total_seconds > 0 and not self.after_id: # This will keep going as long as self.on is True, and timer has not elapsed
                    self.total_seconds -= 1 # Decrementing the time
                    self.after_id = self.root.after(1000, decrement_time)
                else:
                    return


I guess that when switching off the timer, the after function calls second_down nevertheless which decrements self.total_seconds but then in decrement_time the label isn't updated. When starting the timer again, the update happens immediately.

I agree, I tried making some changes just now where I've removed the second_down procedure, since I don't think its having much effect, and I'm now cancelling the current after function that was in operation before stopping the timer; but that still has not solved my issue.

It would help if you could post your code as a single block that we can copy and past.

Now included that in the post.
